# ffprobe arguments not recognized in C#

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, ffprobe

I am executing the below command in cmd and works as expected:

`ffprobe -v quiet -loglevel repeat+level+verbose -print_format json -show_format -show_streams -show_optional_fields always "http://hello.com" > "C:\lolwut.mp4.json" 2> "C:\test.txt"`

In C# code I do the following:

```
string path = "C:\\";

string filename = Path.Combine(path, "ffprobe.exe");
string cParams = @" -v quiet -loglevel repeat+level+verbose -print_format json -show_format -show_streams -show_optional_fields always -i "http://hello.com" > "lolwut.mp4.json" > "test.txt"";
var proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filename, cParams);
```

From the code I the following error:

Argument '>' provided as input filename, but ''http://example.com/'' was already specified.

How should I script the arguments?

I have tried placing the filenames in '' instead of "" but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The redirection operators like > and < are part of the command shell not part of running a process. You need to use the Process Redirection options. Ie the StandardOutput property of the process.

Comment: Thank you your comment pointed me to the coorect direction!